# How to make Listing from web API services using Angular 6

Tags: angular, rest, httpclient

I am new developper in Angular 6. When i make Listing for my project , the project gives thing like [object Object]  on my browser.I use another model for the city's info. Do you think what do i need to do ? you could answer on Angular 5 if you want. I can translate to Angular 5.Could you help me at this issu ?

My json data is ;
{
        "id": "",
        "name": "A bank",
        "address": "adres",
        "contactName": "Jack",
        "contactSurname": "Jones",
        "contactPhone": "+545014877",
        "status": true,
        "city": {
            "id": 40,
            "name": "İSTANBUL",
            "code": 34
        },
        "town": {
            "id": 459,
            "name": "Beyoglu",
            "city": {
                "id": 40,
                "name": "Istanbul",
                "code": 34
            }
        }
    },

- My example output

A bank  adres   Jack Yektan Jones +53789877 true [object Object]    [object Object]

- Model Bank

  ```
      export class Bank{
        id: string;
        name: string;
        address: string;
        contactName: string;
        contactSurname: string;
        contactPhone: string;
        secondContactPhone: string;
        bankLogo: any;
        town: Town;
        city: City;
      }
  ```
- Model City

  ```
  export class City extends ResponseError{
    id: number;
    name: string;
    code: number;
  }
  ```

-My Example Services

```
- My services

    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient/*,HttpHeaders */} from "@angular/common/http";
    import { Bank } from "../models/bank";
    import { Observable } from '../../node_modules/rxjs/Observable';

    @Injectable()
    export class BankService {


    constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

    getContent(): Observable<Bank[]>{
        return this.http.get<Bank[]>('exampleurl');
    }
    }
```

- My Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Bank } from '../models/bank';
import { BankService } from './bank.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-bank',
  templateUrl: './bank.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bank.component.css'],
  providers:[BankService]
})
export class BankComponent implements OnInit {
  title="Bank";
  bank:Bank[];
  constructor(private bankService:BankService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getContent();
  }
  getContent(){
    this.bankService.getContent().subscribe(res=>{this.bank=res;});
  }
}
```

-Html

```
   <tr *ngFor='let bnk of bank;let i = index'>
        <th scope="row">{{ i+1 }}</th>
        <td>{{bnk.name}}</td>
        <td>{{bnk.address}}</td>
        <td>{{bnk.contactName}}</td>
        <td>{{bnk.contactSurname}}</td>
        <td>{{bnk.contactPhone}}</td>
        <td>{{bnk.secondContactPhone}}</td>
        <td>{{bnk.status}}</td>
        <td>{{bnk.bankLogo}}</td>
        <td>{{bnk.town}}</td>
        <td>{{bnk.city}}</td>
      </tr>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Both `town` and `city` are objects. When you do `{{bnk.town}}`, your telling Angular to convert the object into a string, which gives you `[object Object]`. What is it you actually want it to display?

Comment: ı want to show me real name  on my table  screen such as Istanbul , Madrid etc.

Comment: Then change it to `{{bnk.town.name}}` and `{{bnk.city.name}}`

Comment: this is not a solution.( bnk.town.name ).I've tried it before.

Comment: Okay, and what didnt work about that solution?

Comment: if i make its , only one record comes to my screen.But I have a lot of records

Comment: {{bnk.town?bnk.town.name:''}} is a solution but we can not make to every record.

Comment: Okay, you can try `{{bnk?.town?.name}}`

Comment: this is correct answer.we can control 'null' value with ? . thank you a lot.